# How fast remove selected text

Tags: iedit

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10, package `iedit`

Suppose I want to delete text `onMessage`

I select this text by `iedit-mode (C-;)`

[image]

To remove selected text I press many times button `Backspace`

Nice. It's work.

But it slow. Is is possible to delete selected text faster?

Here result:
[image]

P.S. I found solution by `kill-region`
[image]

and after `kill-region`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put point into one of the iedit-occurrences and press <kbd>M-D</kbd> (Meta key, shift key, and `D` key).

That key sequence runs the command `iedit-delete-occurrences` that deletes all occurrences selected by `iedit`.

Note that I tested this with the current git-version of `iedit`. But I found `iedit-delete-occurrences` even in the `v0.9.9.9` tag. So it should work with all current versions of `iedit`.

Answer (score 0):

After you selected all the words `onMessage` in your example using `iedit-mode` your point is usually at the beginning or at the end of the word(s) depending on how you call `iedit-mode`.

`kill-word` or `backward-kill-word` does what you want depending on where the point on the word is.

If the point is on the beginning of the word you can use `kill-word` to kill **all** the marked words. This is bound to `<C-delete>`

If the point is on the end of the word then you can use `backward-kill-word` to kill **all** the marked words. This is bound to `<M-backspace>` or `M-DEL`.

Comment: But if I need to kill many words. Then I need to use kill-region ?

Comment: For me kill-region does not work. Just as backspace in you example kill-word and backward-kill-word operate on all marked words at the same time. I updated my answer a bit. Hope it clarifes things a bit.

Comment: Please clarify in the question whether you want to just *delete* the text or *kill* it. Killing it puts it on the `kill-ring` so you can then yank (paste) it. Deleting it does not do that.

Comment: @andrej I test by kill-region and it's success work. I updated my post

Comment: @Drew no matter. I just need to remove the selected text.